# wso2 micro integrator file connector write operation not working

Tags: file, wso2, connector, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using WSO2 MI 4.1.0 and file connector 4.0.12.

When an api request comes, a simple test of writing to a fixed file is in progress.
but the file is not created without any errors.

my source

- api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/writeFile" name="writeFile" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <file.write configKey="LocalFile2">
                <filePath>write_api.txt</filePath>
                <contentOrExpression>saswswsadsadasds</contentOrExpression>
                <mimeType>Automatic</mimeType>
                <compress>false</compress>
                <writeMode>Create New</writeMode>
                <enableStreaming>false</enableStreaming>
                <appendNewLine>false</appendNewLine>
                <enableLock>false</enableLock>
                <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
                <updateLastModified>true</updateLastModified>
            </file.write>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

local-entries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="LocalFile2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <file.init>
        <workingDir>/apim/file/to/</workingDir>
        <name>LocalFile2</name>
        <fileLockScheme>Local</fileLockScheme>
        <connectionType>LOCAL</connectionType>
    </file.init>
</localEntry>
```

[image: api request and response]

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For the `filepath` parameter in the write operation, you need to have a `/` before the filename.

```xml
<filePath>/write_api.txt</filePath>
```

It seems like a bug in the file connector and I have created an issue to track it at https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/1111

Comment: thank you for your response~! i'm have confirmed that the file was written. In read operation, it works well even without /. I hope it gets fixed properly.